# Building msi with cx_Freeze : ValueError: FCI error 6

Tags: python

I try to make a msi for my  programe with cx_Freeze use python3.5( setup.py bdist_msi ,and get this massege

Screenshot:

[image]

Here is my setup.py:

```
import sys

import os

from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable


build_exe_options = {"optimize": 2,"include_files": ["Frame.py"]}

base = None

if sys.platform == 'win32':base = 'Win32GUI'

os.environ['TCL_LIBRARY'] = r'D:\Python35\tcl\tcl8.6'

os.environ['TK_LIBRARY'] = r'D:\Python35\tcl\tk8.6'


executables = [Executable(script='Frame.py',base=base,)]
```

can you help me?

Comment: i have seen the similar question,i have try but not solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the extra `,` after base, in this line:

```
executables = [Executable(script='Frame.py',base=base,)]
```

Make it:

```
executables = [Executable(script='Frame.py',base=base)]
```

Comment: Removing that trailing comma has zero effect. Truth is, almost 5 years later, I got the same error yesterday (cx_Freeze 6.10) in a project that has been packaged almost every day. I used the Microsoft approach: try again. It worked. Not a solution, but a leap of faith.